# Using two elements with non-unique id in HTML form

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-5

I have a form that I am reusing but the labels are in different languages.

Essentially, a user picks the language from a dropdown and the labels are displayed based on the choice.

However, I have noted since I am reusing the same ids, it's failing and giving warnings `Found 2 elements with non-unique id`.

```
<div class="button dropdown"> 
  <select id="languageselector">
     <option value="english">English</option>
     <option value="swahili">Swahili</option>
  </select>
</div>

 <div id="english" class="language english">
        <form id="reviewForm" method="POST" action="/review/post">
        <div id="reviewFormPage">
        {!! csrf_field() !!}
        {!! Form::hidden('business_name', $provider->businessId, ['class'=>'form-control', 'id' => 'businessId']) !!}
        {!! Form::hidden('acceptTerms', null, ['class'=>'form-control', 'id' => 'acceptTerms']) !!}
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="checkbox icheck">
                        <label>
                        {!! Form::checkbox('existing_customer', '1', false, ['id' => 'existing_customer_review']) !!}
                            I am an existing customer.
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
       </form>
 </div>


 <div id="swahili" class="language swahili">
        <form id="reviewForm" method="POST" action="/review/post">
        <div id="reviewFormPage">
        {!! csrf_field() !!}
        {!! Form::hidden('business_name', $provider->businessId, ['class'=>'form-control', 'id' => 'businessId']) !!}
        {!! Form::hidden('acceptTerms', null, ['class'=>'form-control', 'id' => 'acceptTerms']) !!}
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="checkbox icheck">
                        <label>
                        {!! Form::checkbox('existing_customer', '1', false, ['id' => 'existing_customer_review']) !!}
                            Mimi ni mteja anayerudi.
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
       </form>
 </div>
```

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $('#languageselector').change(function(){
        $('.language').hide();
        $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
      });
    });
</script>
```

So when I select the `swahili` drop down I get an error on the browser. `Found 2 elements with non-unique id #businessId`

I guess this is because I am using the same fields apart from the labels.

I need to keep it this way because it's only the labels that are being changed on selection.

Anyone?

Comment: Instead of using .hide maybe try .css(‘visibility’ , ‘hidden’)

Comment: Or add a class of ‘.invisible’ if using bootstrap and only show the one div if selected

Comment: @CodeBoyCode where exactly do I use this? On the div ids? eg `style="visibility: hidden;"`

Answer (score 0):

In your use case, there is just one line which is changing based on language, So you can do this instead :

```
<div class="button dropdown"> 
  <select id="languageselector">
     <option value="english">English</option>
     <option value="swahili">Swahili</option>
  </select>
</div>

 <div class="language">
        <form id="reviewForm" method="POST" action="/review/post">
        <div id="reviewFormPage">
        {!! csrf_field() !!}
        {!! Form::hidden('business_name', $provider->businessId, ['class'=>'form-control', 'id' => 'businessId']) !!}
        {!! Form::hidden('acceptTerms', null, ['class'=>'form-control', 'id' => 'acceptTerms']) !!}
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="checkbox icheck">
                        <label>
                        {!! Form::checkbox('existing_customer', '1', false, ['id' => 'existing_customer_review']) !!}
                            <!-- See below changes-->
                            <label class="lang-label" lang="english">I am an existing customer.</label>
                            <label class="lang-label" lang="swahili">Mimi ni mteja anayerudi.</label>

                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
       </form>
 </div>


 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $('#languageselector').change(function(){
        $('.lang-label').hide();
        $('.lang-label[lang="' + $(this).val() + '"]').show();
      });
    });
</script>
```

Also see laravel's [localization](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/localization) to move the static text and manage it more efficiently.

Comment: Sorry, I have so many other fields that are changing based on the selection, I just included the two to avoid having a long question.